# Openstack: how object storage to be used by apps running on VM?

Tags: openstack

I'm new to openstack, now reading some documentation. I have question about the object storage.

Could the swift object storage be used by apps running on virtual machine? I guess the answer should be YES. If so, do apps also use the Openstack HTTP based API to operate the storage? I'm afraid the performance issue.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the particular performance issues that you are worried about? Making requests against swift just involved HTTP calls, so it should not be compute-intensive, so CPU performance shouldn't be an issue. Are you worried about network performance of moving lots of data in and out of a VM?

Answer (score 3):

Yep. You can. All external apps interact with OpenStack services via their HTTP API.

Probably the easiest way to interact with Swift is via the python-swiftclient. See

http://docs.openstack.org/cli/quick-start/content/install_openstack_swift_cli.html

If you're using PHP, you might want to consider php-opencloud. See

https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/README.md

If you're using Java, you might want to consider jclouds. See

http://www.jclouds.org/

If you're concerned about performance, I'd suggest doing some performance testing to see if they'll meet your needs.

HTH